Curved Bottom Nav Bar have horizontal reflection on the edges
As mention in the title im trying to make a custom curved bottom nav bar with round edges and transparent curve like this one

and this is the result i have made so far


but as you can see when the selected item is on the most right or left there is a slight reflection to the edge and i've tried so many things to fix it but it seems i can't
here is the CustomNavBarView file
class CurvedBottomNavigationView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : BottomNavigationView(context, attrs) {

    private val path = Path()
    private val paint = Paint()
    private var curveCenterX = 0f
    private val curveHeightFactor = 1.6f
    private val cornerRadius = 120f // Set your desired corner radius


    init {
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE
        paint.color = context.getColor(R.color.md_theme_onPrimary) // Set your desired color
        setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(android.R.color.transparent))
        elevation = 1f
    }

    fun setCurveCenterX(centerX: Float) {
        curveCenterX = centerX
        invalidate()
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        val width = width.toFloat()
        val height = height.toFloat()
        val radius = 160f

        path.reset()
        val controlY = curveHeightFactor * radius // Adjust the factor to change curve height

        // Top-left corner
        path.moveTo(0f, cornerRadius)
        path.arcTo(RectF(0f, 0f, cornerRadius * 2, cornerRadius * 2), 180f, 90f)

        // Top-left to curve transition
        val curveWidth = 1.3f * radius // Increase the curve width
        path.lineTo(curveCenterX - curveWidth / 2, 0f)
        path.quadTo(curveCenterX, controlY, curveCenterX + curveWidth / 2, 0f) // Adjust curve width here

        // Curve to top-right transition
        path.lineTo(width - cornerRadius, 0f)

        // Top-right corner
        path.arcTo(RectF(width - cornerRadius * 2, 0f, width, cornerRadius * 2), -90f, 90f)

        // Right side and bottom
        path.lineTo(width, height)
        path.lineTo(0f, height)

        path.close()
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint)

        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }
}


and here is the xml implementation
<com.grand.ainshihana.core.customTypes.customView.CurvedBottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_10ssp"
            app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@style/Theme.BottomNavigationView.ActiveIndicator"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_selector"
            app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyle.bold"
            app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationViewTextStyle"
            app:itemTextColor="#9DB2CE"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home_selected"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_primary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottomNavigation"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.08"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.94"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/fab_3_rounded"
            app:tint="@color/white"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

all i've managed to know is that this reflection is happening when the curve iteract with round edge
